# nil:NilClass NoMethodError in MD5 program

Tags: ruby, yaml, nomethoderror

I'm creating a tool that will turn passwords into MD5 hashes within a YAML file, while running my program I'm getting the error:

```
md5.rb:20:in `encrypt_md5': undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from main.rb:12:in `main'
        from main.rb:40:in `<main>'
```

From this method:

```
def encrypt_md5
    hash = load_file
    hash[:users][:"#{prompt('Enter username')}"] = 
        {password: prompt("Enter password")}
    save_file(hash)
    exit unless again?('encrypt md5')
end
#Digest::MD5 hasn't been implemented yet
```

I'm not entirely sure what is happening that's causing the `nil:NilClass NoMethodError`, can somebody explain to me what this means and also tell me what I need to change in order for it to work..

Main.rb source:

```
require_relative 'md5.rb'

def main
     puts <<-END.gsub(/^\s*>/, '')
                >
                >To load information type "L" to quit system type "Q"
                >
            END
    input = gets.chomp.upcase
    case input
    when "L"
        encrypt_md5
    when "Q"
        exit_system
    else
        exit_lock
    end
end

def exit_system
    puts "Exiting..."
    exit
end

def exit_lock #Not finished, will lock user out of program
    puts "Locked out, please contact system administrator"
    exit
end

def again? #Not complete
    puts "Encrypt more?"
    input = gets.chomp
    return input =~ /yes/i
end

def prompt( message )
    puts message
    gets.chomp
end
main
```

md5.rb source:

```
require 'yaml'
require 'digest'

private

    def load_file
        File.exist?('info.yml') ? YAML.load_file('info.yml') : {passwords: {}}
    end

    def read_file
        File.read('info.yml')
    end

    def save_file
        File.open('info.yml', 'w') { |s| s.write('info.yml')}
    end

    def encrypt_md5
        hash = load_file
        hash[:users][:"#{prompt('Enter username')}"] = 
            {password: prompt("Enter password")}
        save_file(hash)
        exit unless again?('encrypt md5')
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is probably here:

```
hash = load_file
hash[:users][:"#{prompt('Enter username')}"] = 
  { password: prompt("Enter password") }
```

You're calling the `[]=` method on `hash[:users]`, but `hash[:users]` is `nil`. Since you didn't post the contents of `info.yml`, I can only guess that you have a YAML file like this:

```
users:
  some_user:
    password: foobar
  another_user:
    password: abcxyz
  # ...
```

When you do `YAML.load_file` on that file, you get this Hash:

```
hash = {
  "users" => {
    "some_user" => { "password" => "foobar" },
    "another_user" => { "password" => "abcxyz" },
    # ...
  }
}
```

With this, `hash[:users]` is `nil` because there's no `:users` key, there's only a `"users"` key. While you could jump through some hoops to turn your keys into symbols, it will be far easier to just use string keys everywhere:

```
hash = load_file
hash["users"][prompt('Enter username')] =
    { "password" => prompt("Enter password") }
```

P.S. There are some more problems with your code, in particular here:

```
def save_file
    File.open('info.yml', 'w') { |s| s.write('info.yml')}
end
```

Firstly, you call `save_file(hash)`, but your `save_file` method doesn't take any arguments. This will raise an ArgumentError. Secondly, what the code in this method does is open the file `info.yml` and then write the string `"info.yml"` to that file. What you probably want is something like this:

```
def save_file(hash)
    File.open('info.yml', 'w') {|f| f.write(hash.to_yaml) }
end
```

Comment: Didn't even realize I didn't post the YAML! My bad! Yes it looks like that

Comment: I see what you're talking about with everything, awesome thank you, very much appreciated answer has been accepted